# Creating a function, iterating through arrays, and pushing names

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript and still trying to figure things out. I know little about basics and I ran into this problem and I'm not sure which line of code is wrong. Also, I'm trying to figure out how to console.log lines of code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Create a function named functions.imHere that creates and returns a new array. Within the function, iterate through the students array and use the .push() method to add each student to the new array.

here is my code:

```
functions.imHere = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(students[i]);
            return newArray;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Instantiate array before loop, insert elements inside the loop and return after the loop. Assuming that `students` is accessible within your function, otherwise you have pass `students` as an argument to your function.

```js
functions.imHere = function() {
  var newArray = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(students[i]);
  }
  
  
  return newArray;
};
```